# Customize ToC page layout

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am using memoir, in the document the ToC is inserted after the Introduction chapter. My problem is that the pages occupied by the ToC change the layout, headers and footers disappear, also I have found that the numbering of pages is lost, the pages occupied by the ToC are taken into account in the pagination of the document but not in the links on the ToC elements, to have the right links I have to manually reset the counter of pages after the ToC. I could not find any hint in the memoir manual on how to solve this. (?)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\makepagestyle{front} 
\makeevenhead{front}{\thepage}{A}{FRONT} 
\makeoddhead{front}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark} 
\makepsmarks{front}{ \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}} \makepagestyle{body} 
\makeevenhead{body}{\thepage}{B}{BODY} 
\makeoddhead{body}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark} 
\makepsmarks{body}{ \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}} 

\begin{document} 

\pagestyle{front} 
\chapter{Intro} \lipsum[1-5] 
\newpage \pagestyle{body} 
\tableofcontents 
\newpage 
\chapter{Tks} 
\lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? To simulate a complete document use command `Blinddocument` of package `blindtext` ...

Comment: Thanks Mensch, I´ll prepare it asap

Answer (score 1):

I tried your MWE and to me it did not exhibit the problems you mentioned. There were footers in the chapters and ToC pages, headers on the second and further pages after the first page of a chapter, and the page numbers reported in the ToC were correct.

Some comments:

1) Remember that `memoir` uses the `chapter` (aliased to `plain`) pagestyle for the first page of a chapter. If you want that to be one of your pagestyles then

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{front} % and/or
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{body}
```

at the appropriate places (e.g., after a `\pagestyle{...}` command)

2) In general better to use `\clearpage` than `\newpage` as the former will flush out any pending floats.

3) In general with `memoir` use the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` commands to indicate the three portions of a typical (book) document.

4) Please check that your new pagestyles really do what you want them to do.

5) What happens if you comment out the `\tableofcontents` and extend the chapter texts to multiple  (3 or 4) pages?